# How color console output by jython

Tags: python, jython

I know I can use some python package which invoke the ctypea function "SetConsoleTextAttribute" IF I use python.

I know I can format ANSI char to color output IF I use python.

BUT I use jython

Is there any method to color my output?

If the method can support both sys.stderr and print ,That will be so nice !